# Why is event handled by jQuery's .on() with selector much faster than regular .on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, profiling

I have been fiddling with "pure javascript vs. jQuery" performance for a while. But there are things I just can't understand. I will show it on my test code:

I have this simple HTML structure:

```
<div id="div_regular"></div>
<div id="div_live_wrap">
  <div id="div_live" class="target2">
    <div id="div_live_target" class="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I then attach 3 empty event handlers:

```
var div_regular = document.getElementById('div_regular');
var div_live = document.getElementById('div_live');
var div_live_target = document.getElementById('div_live_target');

function handler() {  }

// regular event attached
$('#div_regular').on('click', handler);
// delegated event attached
$('#div_live').on('click', '.target', handler);
// another delegated event attached
$('#div_live_wrap').on('click', '.target2', handler);
```

Test is done by firing click event on each div. **[JSPerf for this is here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-evetns-regular-vs-delegated)**.

What I can't figure out:

- Why the click on `#div_live` is so much more efficient than click on `#div_regular` ?
- Why click on `#div_live_wrap` is as slow as `#div_regular` even though it should be as efficient as click on `#div_live` ?

Can anybody explain this ? Thank you very much.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-evetns-regular-vs-delegated

Comment: You shouldn't worry about performance here, no one is able to click more than hundred times per second, except maybe Jon Skeet

Comment: BTW, in your example, you don't make event bubble, so only first one fire the handler. This is non biased jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-evetns-regular-vs-delegated/2

Comment: @JeromyFrench I am sorry, but I am little bit lost in your comment. Can you please describe it in more detail as an answer ? I don't know if you have seen JSPerf test for this question here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-evetns-regular-vs-delegated

Comment: I do not think that test is testing what you think it is...

Comment: @Frodik: You are setting `bubbles` to `false`, so event delegation won't work and there is no event handler to be executed in your second test case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initEvent .

Comment: Ya because triggerring event on target element needs this event to bubbles up through DOM to fire any bound handler to any ancestor, that's kind of purpose of delegation

Comment: @FelixKling You nailed it. Please make your comment as answer as it actually answers my question why that is happening.

Comment: I just repeated what @A.Wolff said with slightly different words ;)